# SoftLayer Command Line Interface - SLCLI - Instance Private only node

Tags: python, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I'm looking to instance a private only virtual machine on SoftLayer using the SLCLI. So far this command creates an instance but critically it automatically assigns a Public Interface which I do not want and does not create the machine on the specific Private VLAN I want either:

```
# slcli vs create --image 1060669 --hostname ejkpoc --domain ejk.co.uk --cpu 1 --memory 1 --datacenter lon02 --postinstall https://10.1.1.13/files/bootstrap-rhel-5.sh --billing hourly
```

Any ideas from the community on what to change the commands to to get the desired result? I'll keep hacking away in parallel ...

Thanks
EJK

***************** UPDATE

So having tried some more I now have the correct structure for the command line:

```
slcli vs create --billing=hourly --image=1060669 --hostname=ejkpoc --domain=ejk.co.uk --cpu=1 --memory=1 --datacenter=lon02 --postinstall=https://10.1.1.13/files/bootstrap-rhel-5.sh --vlan-private=1138
```

But this errors with:

```
SoftLayerAPIError(SoftLayer_Exception_Public): Could not obtain network VLAN with id #1138.
```

Cheers
EJK

**************** UPDATE

Definitely the right VLAN ... 1138

[image]

And 1138 is the only integer value I have to act as an ID ...

Thank 
EJK

*********** UPDATE

Nelson was right the VLAN ID is located in the URL so mine was

https://control.softlayer.com/network/vlans/1227409

this line now works and machines are creating on the right private VLAN .. BUT!!! They are coming with a public VLAN too even though I don't want that .. command so far that works

```
slcli vs create --billing=hourly --image=1060669 --hostname=ejkpoc --domain=ejk.co.uk --cpu=1 --memory=1 --datacenter=lon02 --postinstall=https://10.1.1.13/files/bootstrap-rhel-5.sh --vlan-private=1227409
```

The major trouble with the assignment of a public for me is that all of the postinstall bootstrap with attaches to Chef etc. is now registering the FQDN of the public - yuck! 
Cheers
EJK

************ UPDATE

All working now ... I missed out the "--private" option on the above SLCLI command ... Many thanks Nelson !!!

Comment: All working now ... I missed out the "--private" option on the above SLCLI command ... Many thanks Nelson !!!

Answer (score 2):

run the command:

```
slcli vs create --help
```

you will see that to create a VSI in a private network you only need to add the `--private` paramter. also it list how to create the VSI in a specific VLAN:

```
$ slcli vs create --help
Usage: slcli vs create [OPTIONS]

  Order/create virtual servers.

Options:
  -H, --hostname TEXT         Host portion of the FQDN  [required]
  -D, --domain TEXT           Domain portion of the FQDN  [required]
  -c, --cpu INTEGER           Number of CPU cores  [required]
  -m, --memory INTEGER        Memory in mebibytes  [required]
  -d, --datacenter TEXT       Datacenter shortname  [required]
  -o, --os TEXT               OS install code. Tip: you can specify
                              <OS>_LATEST
  --image TEXT                Image ID. See: 'slcli image list' for reference
  --billing [hourly|monthly]  Billing rate  [default: hourly]
  --dedicated / --public      Create a dedicated Virtual Server (Private Node)
  --san                       Use SAN storage instead of local disk.
  --test                      Do not actually create the virtual server
  --export PATH               Exports options to a template file
  -i, --postinstall TEXT      Post-install script to download
  -k, --key TEXT              SSH keys to add to the root user (multiple
                              occurrence permitted)
  --disk TEXT                 Disk sizes (multiple occurrence permitted)
  --private                   Forces the VS to only have access the private
                              network
  --like TEXT                 Use the configuration from an existing VS
  -n, --network TEXT          Network port speed in Mbps
  -g, --tag TEXT              Tags to add to the instance (multiple occurrence
                              permitted)
  -t, --template PATH         A template file that defaults the command-line
                              options
  -u, --userdata TEXT         User defined metadata string
  -F, --userfile PATH         Read userdata from file
  --vlan-public INTEGER       The ID of the public VLAN on which you want the
                              virtual server placed
  --vlan-private INTEGER      The ID of the private VLAN on which you want the
                              virtual server placed
  --wait INTEGER              Wait until VS is finished provisioning for up to
                              X seconds before returning
  -h, --help                  Show this message and exit.

  See 'slcli vs create-options' for valid options
```

Comment: Thanks Nelson and with some more trys/attempts I now have the right command structure but the command errors ... see edit above ... Cheers EJK

Comment: I think you are using the VLAN number right? you need to use the ID of the vlan. please make sure about that

Comment: you can get the VLAN ID via the portal, go Network->IP managment->VLANS , then click  in the VLAN number you want and in the URL you will see a number which is the ID of the VLAN

Comment: Definitely the right/only VLAN ID 1138 ... have pasted update ... the error is interesting in that it references a call to "SoftLayer_Exception_Public" when I've clearly entered a private ...  thanks EJK ...

Comment: okay so trying now with the VLAN ID ... nicely hidden in the URL ... ;-)

Comment: So this now works for the private but the machine has been given a public even though I first went with --vlan-public=0 and then omitted it as an option completely ... so my final ask is how do I make sure the VM gets absolutely no public network ... thanks EJK